Closing selenium Chromes causes "Too many open files"
I have a code that should be constantly running and it uses selenium to maintain a Chrome process. The issue is that sometimes I need to restart it to load a new extension, just clear the browsing data or sometimes it just loses connection to Chrome for no reason. The point is - it happens inevitably. When this happens for some reason there are opened files that are left over which cause the "Too many open files" error after some time. As far as I understand this is cause by zombie processes being left over, so I have created a whole function that tries to combat this without killing the process itself (by the way, killing the process itself only partially clears the number of open files which I check by running lsof | wc -l):
import os
import psutil

def kill_driver(driver): # Only one instance of chrome is running at a time, so this is fine
    try:
        driver.quit() # try to just quit it (sometimes it dies here)
    except:
        try:
            print('Could not quit driver driver, killing...')
            if psutil.pid_exists(driver.service.process.pid): # Checking if it is still with us
                os.kill(driver.service.process.pid, 9) # Killing the process directly
        except: pass
        
    try:
        pid = True
        while pid: # This is meant to get rid of zombie processes
            pid = os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
            try:
                if pid[0] == 0:
                    pid = False
            except:
                pass
        print('Kill successfull')
    except Exception as E:
        if 'No child processes' not in str(E):
            print('Kill failed')

Parts of this code are based on this question
This still does not help, so I even tried sometimes running lsof | grep chrome | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill. This helps, but in the long run some other opened files pile up and I don't know how to find them. Is there any way to fix this issue entirely?

I'd suspect the browser here... are you also killing browser instances?  (You might try instead to send proper shutdown to the browser.  It should run cleanup on close which would probably include all sort of tmp files.  (that might require getting the port/session and/or handle when initiating the driver.... if the driver crashes or looses the session you could then start a new one with that session just to send driver.quit() properly)

though come to think of it, when chromedriver loses the session, it's usually a session timeout, so not sure you can use the sessionID anymore after that.  Might need the handle or debug port to send proper shutdown?
